# ClutterActor properties

Tags: c, glib, clutter

I just started playing around with clutter a bit, and I got a question in regards to setting properties on a ClutterActor.

I want to set the pivot-point property, after searching though the reference, the function which seems the best fit is clutter_container_child_set_property (I couldn't find anything with operated directly on the actor), so I'm trying

```
ClutterPoint point = {128,64};
clutter_container_child_set_property(CLUTTER_CONTAINER(stage), box, "pivot-point", point);
```

But I get an error, it expects the point to be of the type GValue , how do I change the clutter point to a gvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clutter_container_set_property` probably isn't the right way to go, but stuffing a `ClutterPoint` in a `GValue` would look something like this:

```
GValue value;
g_value_init (&value, CLUTTER_TYPE_POINT);
g_value_set_boxed (&value, &point);
```

Once you have that you can use [g_object_set_property](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set-property) to set the [ClutterActor:pivot-point](http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterActor.html#ClutterActor--pivot-point) property:

```
g_object_set_property (G_OBJECT(box), "pivot-point", &value);
```

Or you could just let GObject handle the GValue stuff for you and use [g_object_set](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set):

```
g_object_set (G_OBJECT(box), "pivot-point", &point, NULL);
```

If you don't already have the `ClutterPoint` sitting around for some other reason, the easiest method would be to just use [clutter_actor_set_pivot_point](http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterActor.html#clutter-actor-set-pivot-point):

```
clutter_actor_set_pivot_point (box, 128, 64);
```

Of course, if you do already have the `ClutterPoint`, you can also just use `point.x` and `point.y` instead of `128` and `64`.